# Gostaria de usar corretamente function()

Tags: javascript, html, funções, onclick

Usei uma função quando executada mudasse a imagem que foi clicada, só que gostaria de realizar a mesma função em outras imagens. A única solução que me passou pela cabeça é realizar o mesmo processo em todas as imagens, mas acredito que seria o uso incorreto de função.

```js
function changeImage() {
  let image = document.getElementById("Kled")
  if (image.src.match("Kled.jpg")) {
    image.src = "Imagens/Status01_Kled.jpg"
  } else {
    image.src = "Imagens/Kled.jpg"
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="champions">
  <div class="character">
    <b>Kled</b>
    <img class="image_source" id="Kled" src="Imagens/Kled.jpg" onclick="changeImage()" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="character">
    <b>Wukong</b>
    <img class="image_source" id="Wukong" src="Imagens/Wukong.jpg" onclick="" alt="">
  </div>
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1):

O código pode utilizar de base o parâmetro id e o index que está atualmente. Onde o index seria a forma de você validar em qual exibição ele está. Exemplo:

- 0 = Imagem normal
- 1 = Vendo o Status

Segue exemplo de código a ser utilizado:

```js
const baseUrl = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/loading";

    function changeImage(championImage) {
      championImage.dataset.index = championImage.dataset.index == 0 ? 1 : 0;
      championImage.src = `${baseUrl}/${championImage.id}_${championImage.dataset.index}.jpg`;
    }
```

```css
img {
float:left;
max-width: 100px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<img id="Aatrox" data-index="0" src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/loading/Aatrox_0.jpg" onclick="changeImage(this)">

<img id="Kled" data-index="0" src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/loading/Kled_0.jpg" onclick="changeImage(this)">
```

Answer (score -2):

```
   <div id="resultado"></div>
   <input type="submit" onclick="mostrarResultado()">

   var result = document.getElementById("resultado");

   function mostrarResultado() {
     result.innerHTML = "Hello, world!";
   }
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).